Inconsistent Matching Results with Matchit After Excluding One Patient
I used the R package Matchit for 1:1 nearest neighbor matching without replacement in my study. Here’s the code I used:
R code:
match_formula <- as.formula("group ~ Age + Medication")

matched <- matchit(match_formula, data = df_combined, method = "nearest", 
                    ratio = 1, replace = FALSE, unit.id = 'ID')

Initially, I achieved a well-matched population, confirmed using bal.tab and love.plot. However, after excluding one patient from my intervention cohort, I observed a significant decline in match quality, even though the historical group of possible matches remained unchanged.
My Observations:

The excluded patient was not an outlier and had no unusual characteristics.
I did not expect that removing one patient could adversely affect the match quality, especially since the cohort of possible matches was constant

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the matching with exemplary data because I would have to have the same propensity scores to reproduce the matching.
Questions:

How could excluding a single patient lead to such a decline in matching quality?
Is it possible to still receive a good match if this did not work now?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions.
